XML Viewer Error - Failed to apply XSLT to the content
I'm using (and have for many years) an XML Viewer Web Part to display a comic feed from the following URL: https://www.comicsrss.com/rss/garfield.rss
Then I have the following code in the XSL Transform to display the latest comic strip. This has been working fine in SharePoint Subscription Edition (On-Prem) for 18 months or so and many years on previous versions of SharePoint. One of the latest CU's broke it! I tried the XSLT in http://xsltransform.net/ and it does work, however SharePoint gives me this error: Failed to apply XSLT to the content. Sorry, the code below will not display properly so I have added it as a picture. Sorry.

The LOG is showing this Error:
Exception applying Xsl for XmlWebPart 5c8ec881-e9e9-4e41-a923-66ef1beabea3.
Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XmlWebPart.LoadXslCompiledTransform(String xsl, String webUrl)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XmlWebPart.ApplyXslt(String& contents, String transform)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XmlWebPart.ProcessXml(Object state).   3eec64a1-d982-00d3-658a-68ddd9fa1605
AND
Failed to Deserialize deltaCompiledCustomXslBinary with error Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.SafeSerialization+BlockedTypeException: System.UnitySerializationHolder     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.SafeSerialization.ValidatingBinder.BindToType(String assemblyName, String typeName)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Bind(String assemblyString, String typeString)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltInfo.DeserializeCustomXsl(Byte[] deltaCompilationCustomXslBinary)    50a164a1-69f2-00d3-658a-61845c1d6937
Please help.
Thanks, Dave

UPDATE: It looks like this issue was introduced in the SSSE CU for July 2024 (KB5002606) and is explained here: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/502.html as Deserialization of Untrusted Data. My big question is, how can I change the XSLT to comply with this?

It appears that the XML Viewer Web Part, especially with XSLT, is no longer supported. I was trying to get this working on SharePoint Subscription Edition On-Prem; however, it will not work. I looked for the XML Viewer Web Part in SharePoint Online, just to see, but it's nowhere to be found. So, I resolved the issue by removing the web part and replacing it with a Content Editor Web Part that references a single Text file in a Library. I wrote some C# code to extract what I needed from the RSS XML feed and rewrite the Text file, then upload it to the Library and set it up to run at 7AM each day. So far, it's working!
